# Is it possible to import "GostR3410" standard certificate file into JKS and get Private key using keytool or bouncycastle package with java?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, keytool, gost3410

Is it possible to get a private key from certificate which issued with **"GostR3410-2001-CryptoPro-A"** standard and by an external cryptographic service provider to generate a digital signature with **"ECGOST3410"** algorithm?

I already have that type of certificate including the private key in a pfx file type.

How can I import it into a JKC and get the private key to generate a digital signature using **ECGOST3410_2012Signer** in bouncycastle?

Comment: _"Is it possible to get a private key from certificate"_ -- no, that is the whole point of certificates, the private key is ***private***. If you could get the PK then the certificate would be useless.

Comment: @jim-garrison I have retrieved the private key from a self-signed certificate generated with  "ECGOST3410" algorithm using the bouncycastle package. and there is a way to retrieve the private and public keys
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm

Comment: `I already have that type of certificate including the private key in a PFX file type.`

In most cases you will need to have installed some of Cryptographic Service Provider that support GOST. They almost have some utilities to manipulate PFX files and generate a signature.